# How to handle a missing value while parsing an html via jsoup?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I have a programm that should scrape urls and get all the values of elements. Elements look like this:

`VALUE1 - VALUE3`

or it can look like this:

`VALUE1/VALUE2 - VALUE3`

The HTML file looks this way:

```
 `<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li>
      <a><span>VALUE1</span></a>
       -
      <span>VALUE3</span>
            </li>


 </ul>`
```

Or it can look this way:

```
 `<ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li>
      <a><span>VALUE1</span></a>
       /
      <a><span>VALUE2</span></a>
       -
      <span>VALUE3</span>
            </li>


 </ul>`
```

I need to get the first and third value, so I firstly scrape all of the VALUE1 and put it into an ArrayList, then I do the same with VALUE3. But here's the problem: VALUE3 is not always there! Sometimes the VALUE3 span tag can just not be present on the website.

So when I put my VALUE1 and VALUE3 from 2 lists to one, the first can be larger, which may cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I thought maybe I could just put something in my second list if VALUE3 is missing? Which way can I do that? I use the following code to scrape:

```
                    for (Element row : parse.select("ul>li>a>span")){ //to scrape the first one
                        String ing = row.getAllElements().text();
                        ingDebug1.add(ing);
                        debug = i;
                    }

                    for (Element row :parse.select("ul>li>span")){ //to scrape the third one
                        String ing = row.getAllElements().text();
                        debug = i;
                    }

                    for (int k = 0; k<ingDebug1.size(); k++){ // to put them together
                        ingShowUp.add(ingDebug1.get(k));
                        ingShowUp.add(ingDebug2.get(k));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which presents two ways to filter `li` nodes such that you capture only those which have a `span` as one of its children nodes. (Change the line `.filter(TopicAndDescriptionParser::isValidNode1)` to `.filter(TopicAndDescriptionParser::isValidNode2)` to demonstrate that they yield the same result.)

You didn't clarify how you wanted to collect the related data from each `li`, so I made up the record `TopicAndDescription` to encapsulate it.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TopicAndDescriptionParser {

    record TopicAndDescription(String topic, String description) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String snippet = """
            <ul>
                 <li></li>
                 <li></li>
                 <li></li>
                 <li></li>
                 <li>
                      <a><span>VALUE0</span></a>
                       -
                 </li>
                 <li>
                      <a><span>VALUE1</span></a>
                       -
                      <span></span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a><span>VALUE2</span></a>
                       -
                      <span>VALUE3</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <a><span>VALUE4</span></a>
                       /
                      <a><span>VALUE5</span></a>
                       -
                      <span>VALUE6</span>
                    </li>
             </ul>""";

        final Elements elements = Jsoup.parse(snippet).select("ul>li");
        final List<TopicAndDescription> list = elements.stream()
            .filter(TopicAndDescriptionParser::isValidNode2)
            .map(TopicAndDescriptionParser::getTopicAndDescription)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static boolean isValidNode1(Element elem) {
        /*
         * Node names from your snippet will be: 
         *      #text, a, #text, span, #text
         * or
         *      #text, a, #text, a, #text, span, #text
         *
         * So, check that the *next to last* node name is "span"
         * 
         * Potential drawback: it assumes the index of the "span" node. Any
         * unexpected variation in the HTML may cause it to yield wrong results.
         */
        List<Node> childNodes = elem.childNodes();
        int size = childNodes.size();
        return size > 2 
            && "span".equals(((Element) childNodes.get(size - 2)).tagName())
            && !((Element) childNodes.get(size - 2)).text().isEmpty();
    }

    private static boolean isValidNode2(Element element) {
        /*
         * Is there a span node in the child nodes?
         * 
         * Pro: no indexing; con: using a stream might be consider heavy weight.
         */
        Optional<Node> spanNode = element.childNodes().stream()
            .filter(node -> "span".equals(node.nodeName()))
            .findFirst();
        
        return spanNode.isPresent() && !((Element)spanNode.get()).text().isEmpty();
    }

    private static TopicAndDescription getTopicAndDescription(Element element) {
        String topic = element.select("a:first-child").text();
        Elements spans = element.select("span");
        String description = spans.get(spans.size() - 1).text();
        return new TopicAndDescription(topic, description);
    }

}
```

Output is

```
[TopicAndDescription[topic=VALUE2, description=VALUE3], TopicAndDescription[topic=VALUE4, description=VALUE6]]
```